# Executing a Stopped Process in XV6

Tags: c, process, operating-system, kernel, xv6

I wrote two new system calls and add them to the xv6 OS kernel. So using one system call I can save process state and using the other one I can reload the previous state and continue.
the **problem** is in the **reloading section**.

---

is it enough to reload just the context of the process ? (i mean the `struct context` which contains some CPU register)

Comment: You're the one designing the feature, and I don't know anything about xv6, but here are some things to think about: Virtual memory layout, memory contents, open files, open sockets

Comment: If am i am the future designer then i will change the whole architecture of xv6 , since it dose not have enough document

Comment: You do that, if you want. How long will it take?

Comment: I guess two or three hours is enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

The process may have open files and pipes in `proc->ofile`, which you need to save/load.

Note also that by the time you re-load a process, its `parent` may no longer exist.
You'll really want to make sure your process isn't floating around without a real parent, or you'll be in for some fun bugs.